# PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: database, blocks, caching

In my site, I get the following error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cambodia_ohchrProduction.ohchr_cache_block' doesn't exist: TRUNCATE {cache_block} ; Array ( ) in cache_clear_all() (line 167 of /home/cambodiaohchr/public_html/includes/cache.inc).

How can I fix problem?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! This question is too broad. We cannot debug a site to which we don't have access. We can give general advices, but they would not be much helpful to future readers.

Comment: Looks like an issue with database prefixes. Your settings.php file will have this setting and will need to be adjusted most likely.

Comment: This error happen when we try to update the content from backend. or we try to do any optration from the backend.

Answer (score 0):

This error happened to me before, I don't really know why but the only solution that I can really tell you (and it worked for me) is to get some **Database backup** that you may have saved (from a past date) and export the schemas from the tables **cambodia_ohchrProduction** and **revision_cambodia_ohchrProduction** into your actual site .

Remember just the **schemas of those 2 tables**.

And that should work!

Answer (score 0):

try to follow this steps they may work for you :

1. Connect to the **cambodia_ohchrProduction** database and create the **ohchr_cache_block** table
2. clear the cache and test if you have no error.
3. remove the table that has been create at step 1 and clear the cache again.